# Is it possible to calucate the edit distance between a regexp and a string?

Tags: regex, distance, levenshtein-distance

If so, please explain how.

**Re: what is distance** -- "The distance between two strings is defined as the minimal number of edits required to convert one into the other."

For example, xyz to XYZ would take 3 edits, so the string xYZ is closer to XYZ and xyz.

If the pattern is [0-9]{3} or for instance 123, then a23 would be closer to the pattern than ab3.

How can you find the shortest distance between a regexp and a non-matching string?

The above is the [Damerau–Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) distance algorithm.

Comment: I think we need a little more info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Finite State Machines to do this efficiently (that is, linear in time).  If you use a transducer, you can even write the specification of the transformation fairly compactly and do far more nuanced transformations than simply inserts or deletes - see wikipedia for [Finite State Transducer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer) as a starting point, and software such as the FSA toolkit or FSA6 (which has a not entirely stable [web-demo](http://odur.let.rug.nl/~vannoord/fsademo/)) too.  There are lots of libraries for FSA manipulation; I don't want to suggest the previous two are your only or best options, just two I've heard of.

If, however, you merely want the efficient, approximate searching, a less flexibly but already-implemented-for-you option exists: [TRE](http://laurikari.net/tre/), which has an [approximate matching function](http://laurikari.net/tre/documentation/regaexec/) that returns the cost of the match - i.e., the distance to the match, from your perspective.

Comment: **@Eamon Nerbonne:** Thanks Eamon, I was going to ask you on my other questions, but figured I'd just work my way to answer... this was a huge help, and TRE looks great! Cheers! (You rock!)

Comment: **@Eamon Nerbonne:** +1 For being a regex master, having a great answer, and editing my question... :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the string with the smallest levenshtein distance between the closest matched string and a sample, then I'm pretty sure it can be done, but you'd have to convert the Regex to a DFA yourself, then try to match and whenever something fails, non-deterministically continue as if it had passed and keep track of the number differences. you could use A* search or something similar for this, it would be quite inefficient though (O(2^n) worst case)